# W3 CSS Responsive to Only Mobile View

Tags: html, amazon-s3, mobile, responsive-design, w3-css

I am creating a [website](http://mughalarch.com). I went to bed at 4 am this morning, and my website, html, and stylesheets were all set with no problems.  I looked at my website an hour ago, and no matter what the screen size is, my website will only appear in the Mobile view, vertically stacked w3-containers.  It is almost like somebody went into my html files and erased every w3-row tag.

This website has been my life for the past 6 months, so I am panicking.  Please help me.  I am not from this profession, so please take it easy on me, and avoid the condescending heckling, however tempting it may be.

Thanks,
Nina

Comment: I just noticed that it is as if my own stylesheet is not working.

Comment: I was having a problem with edits on my stylesheet not appearing on my pages yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened.  It is really bizarre.  I am not sure how this happened.  I would love to know.

My html was linked to the w3 stylesheet by using their web link, and next on the list, I linked to my own stylesheet through my aws S3. (My style sheet should have overrode w3's.)

After screwing around with different ideas, just for the hell of it, I downloaded w3's actual stylesheet and uploaded it to my aws S3 account.  Then I linked the w3 stylesheet with a link from my own domain and listed it first in the head.  Then I copied and pasted my own style sheet into a new document and uploaded that and linked.

Voila! Everything is good and well with the world.

So how and why did this happen within a 4 hour period?

Cheers,
Nina